# Connecting different font files of the same font to the corresponding CSS styles

Tags: css, fonts

On myfonts.com I purchased the [Didot font](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/didot-etext-pro/) which comes in regular, bold, italics and bold italics (one separate file for each of these styles).

When my WordPress users write articles with bold and italic characters, I want the corresponding font style to be used.

But so far, it is always the regular font which is used, even for italics or bold. As a result, the italics that I see on my site seem to be an "italics version" of my regular font. But this result is different from the real italics that is advertized on myfonts.com.

Their customer service is unable to help with these "development issues" in their own words. How can the proper font file be used for each style on my WordPress site?

Here is the code to add in CSS that myfonts.com provides with the files:

```
@import url("//hello.myfonts.net/count/xxxxx");

@font-face {font-family: 'LinotypeDidoteTextPro';font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx1.eot');src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx1.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx1.woff') format('woff'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx1.ttf') format('truetype');}

@font-face {font-family: 'LinotypeDidoteTextPro';font-weight: bold;font-style: italic;src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx2.eot');src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx2.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx2.woff') format('woff'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx2.ttf') format('truetype');}

@font-face {font-family: 'LinotypeDidoteTextPro';font-weight: normal;font-style: italic;src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx3.eot');src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx3.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx3.woff') format('woff'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx3.ttf') format('truetype');}

@font-face {font-family: 'LinotypeDidoteTextPro';font-weight: bold;font-style: normal;src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx4.eot');src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx4.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx.woff') format('woff'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx4.ttf') format('truetype');}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your @font-face declarations are all the same. you need them to each be different(LinotypeDidoteTextPro-normal, LinotypeDidoteTextPro-bold-italic, LinotypeDidoteTextPro-italic, LinotypeDidoteTextPro-bold) in order to use the declarations in your css. Also using classes like "bold" and "italic" instead of elements like "b" and "i" allow you to use the bold italic font properly, otherwise you have to choose which one to use.

CSS File should be:

```
@font-face {font-family: 'LinotypeDidoteTextPro-normal'; src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx1.eot');src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx1.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx1.woff') format('woff'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx1.ttf') format('truetype');}

@font-face {font-family: 'LinotypeDidoteTextPro-bold-italic'; src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx2.eot');src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx2.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx2.woff') format('woff'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx2.ttf') format('truetype');}

@font-face {font-family: 'LinotypeDidoteTextPro-italic'; src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx3.eot');src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx3.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx3.woff') format('woff'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx3.ttf') format('truetype');}

@font-face {font-family: 'LinotypeDidoteTextPro-bold'; src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx4.eot');src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx4.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx.woff') format('woff'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx4.ttf') format('truetype');}

body{
    font-family: "LinotypeDidoteTextPro-normal";
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;    
}
i,
.italic{
    font-family: "LinotypeDidoteTextPro-italic";   
}
b,
.bold{
    font-family: "LinotypeDidoteTextPro-bold";   
}
b i,
i b,
.bold.italic{
    font-family: "LinotypeDidoteTextPro-bold-italic";    
}
```

As @Albert pointed out (reference: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/font-face_tip_define_font-weight_and_font-style_to_keep_your_css_simple/) you can work better with the browsers and be forced to override less if you use font-style and font-weight in your font-face declarations. So an optimized version would be:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LinotypeDidoteTextPro';
    src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx1.eot');
    src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx1.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx1.woff') format('woff'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx1.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'LinotypeDidoteTextPro';
    src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx2.eot');
    src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx2.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx2.woff') format('woff'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx2.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'LinotypeDidoteTextPro';
    src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx3.eot');
    src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx3.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx3.woff') format('woff'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx3.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'LinotypeDidoteTextPro';
    src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx4.eot');
    src: url('webfonts/xxxxxxx4.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx.woff') format('woff'),url('webfonts/xxxxxxx4.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;}

body{
    font-family: "LinotypeDidoteTextPro";
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;    
}
i, .italic{ font-style: italic; }
b, .bold{ font-weight: bold; }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "calling them in the CSS"? Remember the html code contains only b tags and i tags. Somehow, these b and i tags must call different font files.

Comment: Can someone please tell me why this would be downvoted...? it works great and is correct!

Comment: i downvoted it because you're not declaring the fonts correctly. you're syntax is fine, except you should be declaring the font-xyx along with the font...so where you are declaring italic, you should be setting font-style:italic. i'm hesitant to say "should"...imo, that is the correct way to call fonts, and you should notice a visible difference in rendering cross-browser

Comment: I have never seen a call with those in the '@font-face' declaration and if you look at resources that clearly are the standard for how to setup '@font-face' none of them ever mention or show putting those into the actual call. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/ The whole point of using fonts that are the actual font-weight or style is to not have ot force the browser to render them. You really need to do your research before down-voting, especially if the downvote is based on your opinion!

Comment: DrCord: as I said, my users will just click on bold buttons and italics buttons in their text editor, so the html will NOT contain any classes, only b and i tags. I want the text between b tags and i tags to be displayed using the corresponding font file.

Comment: I left the b and I related classes in, but I am modifying my answer slightly to work with the bold italic font.

Comment: @drake035 are you still having issue(s)...if you're not going to share url, make a fiddle real quick like...it's more than likely small subtle differences....perhaps b has been reset to not render as bold? it is impossible to tell without markup and styles.

Answer (score 1):

you're close, you just need to clean up your syntax: here's how i declare open sans regular for font-weights: regular and bold:

```
@font-face{font-family:"open_sansregular";
src:url("http://dev.bowdenweb.com/a/fonts/sans-serif/open-sans/open-sans-regular.eot");
src:url("http://dev.bowdenweb.com/a/fonts/sans-serif/open-sans/open-sans-regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
 url("http://dev.bowdenweb.com/a/fonts/sans-serif/open-sans/open-sans-regular.woff") format("woff"),
 url("http://dev.bowdenweb.com/a/fonts/sans-serif/open-sans/open-sans-regular.ttf") format("truetype"),
 url("http://dev.bowdenweb.com/a/fonts/sans-serif/open-sans/open-sans-regular.svg#open_sansregular") format("svg");
font-weight:normal; font-style:normal}

@font-face{font-family:"open_sansregular";
src: url("http://dev.bowdenweb.com/a/fonts/sans-serif/open-sans/bold/open-sans-bold.eot");
src: url("http://dev.bowdenweb.com/a/fonts/sans-serif/open-sans/bold/open-sans-bold.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
 url("http://dev.bowdenweb.com/a/fonts/sans-serif/open-sans/bold/open-sans-bold.woff") format("woff"),
 url("http://dev.bowdenweb.com/a/fonts/sans-serif/open-sans/bold/open-sans-bold.ttf") format("truetype"),
 url("http://dev.bowdenweb.com/a/fonts/sans-serif/open-sans/bold/open-sans-bold.svg#open_sansbold") format("svg");
font-weight:bold; font-style:normal}
```

continue that code for the rest of your @font-face declarations, swapping out file urls and font-weight/font-style/font-(etc) and also make sure that this is declared atop the first style sheet in your document. you can see the whole thing here: http://dev.bowdenweb.com/a/css/sandbox01.css
also, i used fontsquirrel to generate the different font file formats.

Comment: This is not correct, you do not want to declare the style and weight in the @font-face declaration.

Comment: .....did you look @ what those declarations are doing? notice they have the same font-family name? and yet they are different fonts? they do need the fonts characteristics (weight/style/slant/etc).

Comment: Yeah, using the same name for all the fonts is not the way I have seen the spec implemented.

Comment: depending on your use cause, its optimal so that you are not resetting/redeclaring unnecessary styles, essentially its better for rendering, wpo, etc. i swear by this arcticle: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/font-face_tip_define_font-weight_and_font-style_to_keep_your_css_simple/

Comment: Looks like good info, thanks. too bad the generators don't do it this way.

Comment: agreed. make life so much easier. i just generate one for each on font squirrel, dump them into one folder, cut and splice until they are in one style sheet. its going . icon font explosion the past two years have also led to all types of font automation tools...this is down the pipeline...somewhere!

Comment: Yeah, thanks again for the additional info and desire to fully educate.

Comment: np...actually glad you stuck it out and didn't quit. so many users do that...we aren't here to fight. we are here to learn. we are wrong on here alot. ;)

Comment: I amended my answer to include more info to help users who might only look at the answer marked as correct.

Comment: lol....does he have a solution yet? also good for you...take all you can from here.